# Java insert record into Oracle 9i

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm trying insert a record into Oracle through JDBC. However, it return

```
"ORA-20999: 735014|Unable to make amendment - session was not initialised" when execute the executeUpdate statement.
```

here is the SQL:

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
result = stmt.executeUpdate("insert into test_table (ID, LOCATION) select '1', LOCATION from test_table where rownum=1");
```

Any idea to fix it??

Comment: ORA-20999 is defined as a "user-specified message", meaning that it is reserved for a custom application not part of Oracle.  You seem to be interacting not with the database, but with some intermediary application, and without knowing which application, we can't really help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your database is using row-level security, i.e. you don't have the same access rights for all rows of a table. Instead the rights depend on some context information, e.g. the department you belong to.

Row-level security requries that the context be initialized before you can access the data so the database knows what department you belong to (or whatever the required context information is).

Once you have an open database session, you probably have to call a certain PL/SQL procedure first before you can select or insert data. The database administrator or - in case of a commercial software package - the software manufacturer can certainly tell you more about it.

Comment: Thank you so much. It really row-level security problem. finally, i'm using callable statement to run the certain PL/SQL procedure first before insert data.

Comment: Please accept this answer if it was helpful. It's the official way to give feedback to the Stackoverflow community so they know which answer to follow if they encounter the same problem.